# Remove Chrome shortcuts from app menu

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, webapps

Anyone knows how to remove "web apps" I made in Chrome ***using menu => extra => create shortcuts (no real Chrome apps)*** from the app menu in Ubuntu? When right-clicking on a normal app (Thunderbird in this case), I see this:

[image]

I use Dutch language but I think it's obvious: note the "Deïnstalleren" (uninstall) button next to the start button. But, when I right-click on a Chrome web app (which I made from the menu => extra => create shortcuts), in this case Facebook, it shows me this:

[image]

Note the difference? No uninstall option. Can I achieve this in another way? Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I'm not a professional. I use Ubuntu three days now. Please keep it simple for me. :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Remove it from Chrome.

Go to `chrome://apps`, right click the app you want to remove and select `Remove from Chrome`.

Those are Chrome desktop apps, not Ubuntu apps installed through `Software Center` or from `deb` package. That's why you can't remove them from Unity.

If it doesn't work, go to `~/.local/share/applications` and look there for specific `desktop` files by ID. For example:

[image]

has the shortcut `chrome-njkkjobcechefaoknodniidfjapgfoco-Default.desktop`

Comment: Note that in chrome://apps you'll only find Chrome Apps, and not the shortcuts to random websites you made. But those launchers can be found in '~/.local/share/applications' as Cornelius said.

Comment: Sometimes the name of the files doesn't indicate the app that it opens. Example: `chrome-gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm-Default.desktop`. Try searching within the files. For example, if I created a desktop app for Gmail, I'll search `grep -r ~/.local/share/applications -e 'Gmail'`.

Comment: Removing Chrome apps by deleting all `chrome-*` files in `~/.local/share/applications` is a handy way to remove them if they've been left behind and Chrome is no longer installed on your system. Really useful to know!